# Cannot inject transpostBuilder

Tags: magento2

I was trying to send by email following to [this blog](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-send-an-email-in-magento-2/), where they inject transportBuilder object .

```
public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
        ) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}
```

but when i try to do the same it says:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Company\Module\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder, instance of Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given
```

Not sure where im doing wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action class looks like:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Sendmail.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;


class Sendmail extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Recipient email config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'test/email/send_email';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $_escaper;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
    }

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            $sender = [
                'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['name']),
                'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['email']),
            ];

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('send_email_email_template') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage(); ;
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'.$e->getMessage())
            );
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Delete 'var/generation/*'**

Comment: Delete 'var/generation/*'   works for me . Looks like Magento saves the order in which the objects are injected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following that blog to the letter then they have their name spaces set up like Magento 1.  They're using app/code/local/Company/Module instead of just app/code/Company/Module.  Try moving it all to app/code/Company/Module, run bin/magento setup:upgrade, clear your cache and var/generation/ folders and see if that helps.